# How to reset Firefox' RSS feed handling

Tags: firefox, rss

As a developer I want to view the raw RSS feeds from my application.

But Firefox keeps taking me to a Google page and wants me to tell whether I would like to subscribe in Google Reader or Google IG

I'm desperately seeking the button labeled "just let me view the raw RSS feed" button.

Very annoying behaviour. And "View Source" lets me view source on the actual google page.

Any suggestions on how to bypass this feature/annoyance in Firefox?

PS. I am aware that I probably once upon a time accepted a setting. But there is absolutely no clue on how I disable that setting again -- even though it's probably my own fault.

Comment: As an example of this, the current page here has an RSS feed. But the link to it becomes http://www.google.com/ig/add?feedurl=http%3A%2F%2Fsuperuser.com%2Ffeeds%2Fquestion%2F81892 when I click on it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Goto `Tools`-> `Options` -> `Applications`. In the search box, type 'Web feed' and change it from 'Use Google` to Preview in Firefox.

[image]

Comment: I have searched in that field, but "RSS" returned no results...

Comment: @Palimondo it's "feed" or "web feed", not "RSS"

Comment: @Sathya Now I know, thanks to your answer. I was just explaining how _I've_ missed it, even when searching in the right place ;-)