# How do I show raw XML for an RSS feed in Firefox?

Tags: rss, xml, firefox, atom-feed

Internet Explorer has this option, *Turn on feed reading view*:

[image: Option for Feed reading view]

When unchecked, clicked [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(standard)) feeds will show as raw XML.

How can I do the same thing in Firefox?

Answer (score 4):

You could write this in your browser's Internet address bar:

```
view-source:{RSS-FEED-URI}
```

Comment: Yes, this works (but ***without the braces***). Example: `view-source:https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/forth`

Comment: {RSS-FEED-URI} is a placeholder.

Comment: doesn't seem to work anymore :/

Comment: which versions of firefox have you? Seems that the new versions doesn't support it.Thank you for the error reporting.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: [Feed Proxy](http://persistent.info/feed-proxy/).

It allows you to see the raw feed source.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  However, I will need to have my feed be an authenticated feed.  Feed Proxy does not allow that.  (Also, I was hoping that now that firefox 5 is out that this limitation has been "fixed".)

Comment: Check this: http://superuser.com/questions/81892/how-to-reset-firefox-rss-feed-handling

Comment: Alas, this does not give you the xml view.  It just shows how to open (or not open in this case) a webfeed in another application.  I guess I can just have firefox open in IE, but that seems kind of lame.

Comment: @Vaccano, there seems to be a hack. It is for 2.x though
http://www.walkernews.net/2007/11/20/how-to-view-rss-feed-in-xml-format-with-firefox/